# Как передать скриншот, сделанный pyautogui, через socket?

Tags: python, python-3.x, сокет, pyautogui

Я попытался сделать так, чтобы я мог видеть рабочий стол со своего ноутбука, без сторонних программ, но при передаче скриншота pyautogui в сокет я потерял тип Image, и там был str, я спросил gpt, он ничего не толкового сказал.
Клиент:

```
import socket
import pyautogui
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = 'ip'
port = 'port'
s.connect((host, port))
img = pyautogui.screenshot()
s.send(img)
```

Сервер:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = 'localhost'
port = 'port'
s.bind((host, port))

s.listen(1)
print('wait to connect...')

conn, addr = s.accept()
print(f'{addr} conncted to you!')

data = conn.recv(1024)
data.save()
```

Comment: на Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно закодировать файл при отправке и отправлять частями, это можно сделать следующим образом:

Во первых, нужно поменять код сервера, сделать его более гибким для нескольких клиентов:

**server.py**

```py
import socket
  
if __name__ == '__main__':
    host = '127.0.0.1'
    port = 8080
    totalclient = 1 # Количество клиентов 
  
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.bind((host, port))
    sock.listen(totalclient)

    # Список подключений
    connections = []
    print('Инициализация клиентов...')
    for i in range(totalclient):
        conn = sock.accept()
        connections.append(conn)
        print('Подключение к клиенту ', i + 1)
  
    fileno = 0
    idx = 0

    for conn in connections:
        # Получение данных файла
        idx += 1
        data = conn[0].recv(1024).decode()
  
        if not data:
            continue

        # Создание нового файла на сервере и запись данных
        filename = 'screenshot'+str(fileno)+'.png'
        fileno = fileno + 1
        fo = open(filename, "w")

        while data:
            if not data:
                break
            else:
                fo.write(data)
                data = conn[0].recv(1024).decode()
  
        print()
        print('Получение файла с клиента', idx)
        print()
        print('Файл успешно получен! Название файла:', filename)
        fo.close()

    # Закрытие всех подключений
    for conn in connections:
        conn[0].close()
```

И изменить код отправки скриншота клиентом:

**client.py**

```py
import socket
import pyautogui

if __name__ == '__main__':
    host = '127.0.0.1'
    port = 8080

    # Создание клиентского сокета
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    # Подключение к серверу
    sock.connect((host, port))
  
    while True:
        try:
            img = pyautogui.screenshot()

            # Считывание файла и отправка его на сервер
            fi = open(img, "r")
            data = fi.read()
            if not data:
                break
            while data:
                sock.send(str(data).encode())
                data = fi.read()

            # Закрытие файла после отправки
            fi.close()
  
        except IOError:
            print('Файл не распознан!')
```

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: Если мой ответ помог вам, то прошу отметить его как ответ :) Всегда пожалуйста!